# Grails + MySQL - BasicDataSource or JNDI

Tags: grails, jdbc, jndi

I need to deploy an app in Grails with MySQL.

What's the difference between using a basic datasource or JNDI in performance?

Answer (score 3):

There shouldn't be any performance difference, as long as they're configured similarly. They'll both pool connections, and return a pre-connected instance on demand.

Where you'll see differences is in configuration. Often JNDI datasources are better at testing dead connections, and closing and re-creating them. This is easy to do with a DataSource in Grails though, because you can configure a `properties` block that specifies whether to test connections periodially, or when they're retrieved from the pool, etc. Newer versions of Grails have an example block configured, so it's easy to change the settings.

The only complication is that pool providers have little consistency in property names. Sometimes the password is set with the `password` property and sometimes it's `pass`. The same goes for settings like `testOnBorrow`, `testWhileIdle`, etc. But this is a problem both for the JNDI pool and the Grails DataSource. In both cases you need to know how to configure the pool you're using.

My preference is to do the configuration in the application, because I prefer a self-contained WAR. You can always change the pool provider to use a more robust implementation. Note that newer versions of Grails use the [Tomcat JDBC Pool](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html) (which is independent of whether you use Tomcat as your server) and they have benchmarks that show that it performs better than most other implementations. And you can always install that yourself by installing the [jdbc-pool](http://grails.org/plugin/jdbc-pool) plugin.